# For what stands the "RED" in Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I work with Node-RED every day. Today a colleague asked me for what the "RED" stands for in "Node-RED". I had no answer. In the documentation I have found nothing.

Can someone help?

Comment: This really is off topic for Stack Overflow. Questions like this would be better asked on Slack or the Google group

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't stand for anything, it's just a name Nick and Dave came up with

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was a play on the famous expression:"Code-RED".  Like in the movies or hospital shows as in:  "They've launched their missiles.  Bring us 
to Code RED!"